# SQL Parsing Error when trying to parse from prompt

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, parsing

I am trying to build a function to add a new line to a SQL table, but when I run it I get the following:

```
    const localErr = new Error();
                     ^

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`title` = 'Red', `sala
ry` = '50000', `department_id` = 3' at line 4
    at PromiseConnection.query (C:\Users\corri\dev\classwork\Module-12\challenge\employee-tracker-M12HW\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:93:22)
    at DB.addRole (C:\Users\corri\dev\classwork\Module-12\challenge\employee-tracker-M12HW\db\index.js:62:42)
    at addRole (C:\Users\corri\dev\classwork\Module-12\challenge\employee-tracker-M12HW\server.js:103:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO \n' +
    '                role (title, salary, department_id)\n' +
    '            VALUES \n' +
    "                `title` = 'Red', `salary` = '50000', `department_id` = 3",
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`title` = 'Red
', `salary` = '50000', `department_id` = 3' at line 4"
}
```

Here is the Database:

```
CREATE TABLE role (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
salary DECIMAL (10, 2),
department_id INT,
CONSTRAINT fk_department FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES department(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);

Here is my index.js call:

```
    addRole(role) {
    return this.connection.promise().query(
        `INSERT INTO 
            role (title, salary, department_id)
        VALUES 
            ?`, role
    )
};
```

And here is the function:

```
async function addRole() {
// Pull options so user can select a department to correspond with this role
const [department] = await db.viewAllDepartments();
const departmentChoices = department.map(({ id, name }) => ({
    name: name,
    value: id
}));
const role = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'title',
        message: 'What is the title of the role?'
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'salary',
        message: 'what is the salary of the role?'
    },
    {
        type: 'list',
        name: 'department_id',
        message: 'Which department is this role a part of?',
        choices: departmentChoices
    }
]);
await db.addRole(role);
console.log(`Added ${role.name} to the database`);
mainMenu();
}
```

I've tried adjusting it and I just can't figure out what is parsing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the  brackets ( )
When insert into ... values you should put them within `(` and ')'
its not a set command.

Update:
Also the statement itself is wrong = not an ansi sql one.

This is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO role (title, salary, department_id) VALUES title = 'Red', salary = '50000', department_id = 3"
```

Instead it should be:

```
INSERT INTO role (title, salary, department_id) VALUES ('Red', '50000', 3)
```

Comment: the parenthesis did resolve the error, but now it is just entering null:  (Screenshot) https://share.getcloudapp.com/mXuP0YWA

Comment: this is wrong:
INSERT INTO role (title, salary, department_id) VALUES  `title` = 'Red', `salary` = '50000', `department_id` = 3"

This is valid:
INSERT INTO role (title, salary, department_id) VALUES  ('Red',  '50000', 3)

Comment: I am just feeding the answers from the inquirer prompt into the db here: await db.addRole(role);
When I console.log(role) I get { title: 'Red', salary: '850000', department_id: 2 }
I'm not sure where the equals signs are coming from.